# How to map one entity class with four table in hibernate which have same sql schema?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

> I have four tables with the same  sql schema

```
user_1
+------+--------+----------------------+
| code | name   | pass                 |
+------+--------+----------------------+
|    1 | rajiv  | 12345                |
+------+--------+----------------------+

user_2
+------+--------+----------------------+
| code | name   | pass                 |
+------+--------+----------------------+
|    1 | rajiv1  | 12345               |
+------+--------+----------------------+

user_3
+------+--------+----------------------+
| code | name   | pass                 |
+------+--------+----------------------+
|    1 | raji2  | 12345                |
+------+--------+----------------------+


user_4
+------+--------+----------------------+
| code | name   | pass                 |
+------+--------+----------------------+
|    1 | raji3  | 12345                |
+------+--------+----------------------+
```

> I dont want to make 4 entity class  for these table
>
> Is there any way so that i  can define only one Entity class  and map
>   all four tables to that entity so that i can fetch data from whichever
>   table i want to

Answer (score 0):

In case your database supports views I would recommend to create a view that contains data from all four tables and map this view to one entity. This might be simpler and cleaner than trying to map 4 tables into one entity.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create one table and add attribute usernumber to it, when building the association with your entity create four references each one of them has different usernumber and all mapped to the same table.

Another way if your entity has an association with each user table, create a class user and make it Embeddable using annotation "@Embeddable", In your entity override the name of the columns

```
         @AttributeOverrides({
         @AttributeOverride(name =  "code",column=@Column(name="user1_code"))})
         private User user1;

         @AttributeOverrides({
         @AttributeOverride(name =  "code",column=@Column(name="user2_code"))})
         private User user2;
```

Note this will not map to another table instead it will merge the columns of each user to your entity